# Xcodes UI Testing - Tapping an x y location

Tags: ios, xcode, coordinates, tap, xcode-ui-testing

I am trying to tap an x, y location, while using Xcode and UI Testing.  Here is my code:

```
 XCUIApplication().coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVector(dx: 50, dy: 50)).tap()
```

The middle of the button is definitely at that location and cannot be identified as an individual object (hence using the x, y coordinates).

However, this is not pressing the button.  Anyone know if there is a correct way of tapping an x y coordinate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `dx` and `dy` are not pixel offsets but normalized vectors. For example, 0.5 is actually the middle of the element. Your code is trying to tap an element outside of the screens bounds (by ~50x!).

I suggest trying to solve the problem with a different approach. First off, why can't the button be identified? What have you tried? Are you using a custom `UIButton` subclass?

I ask because you can (usually) expose any control or UI element to UI testing with the right accessibility attributes. For example, you can set `accessibilityLabel` and `accessibilityIdentifier` to the button's text. Then you can use that value to access the button under test.

````
// Production Code
let button = UIButton()
button.setTitle("Save", forState: .Normal)
button.accessibilityIdentifier = "Save"

// UI Test Code
```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.buttons["Save"].tap()
````

Comment: Joe - thanks for the heads up re 50x! oops.  We have tried accessibility labels, ids and hints but this page is proving hideous for some unknown reason. Devs still debugging why but I said I would try an x, y approach in the meantime. Will try some 0.x values - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use dx: 1.5 to click 50% to the right of an element.  I used this on an app that has a a webView that I don't control.